# Set NSTimer to nil crash

Tags: crash, nstimer, invalidation

When I called NSTimer -[invalidate] method and set timer to nil, there caused carsh.The thread that I initialize NSTimer and call -[invalidate] method was the same thread.but it crashed sometimes。why?Bad access crash? This is crash log:

```
 #0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1819d4430 objc_msgSend + 16
1  MTXX                           0x100d73480 -[MTBDummyWebViewViewController resetTimerAndAnimation] (MTBDummyWebViewViewController.m:135)
2  MTXX                           0x100d73828 -[MTBDummyWebViewViewController webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:] (MTBDummyWebViewViewController.m:176)
3  UIKit                          0x18bda4f9c -[UIWebView webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:] + 300
4  CoreFoundation                 0x182779670 __invoking___ + 144
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1826586cc -[NSInvocation invoke] + 292
6  CoreFoundation                 0x18265d16c -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 60
7  WebKitLegacy                   0x18b811858 -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 156
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1827773bc ___forwarding___ + 624
9  CoreFoundation                 0x18265d01c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
10 CoreFoundation                 0x182779670 __invoking___ + 144
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1826586cc -[NSInvocation invoke] + 292
12 WebCore                        0x18a4d34f4 HandleDelegateSource(void*) + 108
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18271a2e8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
14 CoreFoundation                 0x18271a268 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
15 CoreFoundation                 0x182719af0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1827176c8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
17 CoreFoundation                 0x182637fb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
18 GraphicsServices               0x1844cff84 GSEventRunModal + 100
19 UIKit                          0x18bc0c2e8 UIApplicationMain + 208
20 MTXX                           0x10047f6bc main (main.m:15)
21 libdyld.dylib                  0x18215a56c start + 4

--
```

They are used like this:

```
[self.timeoutTimer invalidate];
self.timeoutTimer = nil;
```